meaning of: homogeneity of the coefficient for all levels?
What is the meaning of the "bold" part?
"Moreover, the effect of the interaction between the composting period (of 7 and 10 weeks, respectively) and additives is statistically significant (Pvalue < 0.01), meaning that it can assume the homogeneity of the coefficient for the covariate across the levels of the factor ."
I think that the factor is the 7 or 10 weeks. To the covariate (additives) is attributed a coefficient -I get the superficial meaning of the sentence. But I don't understand why the statistical significance means that the coefficient is homogenous across all levels. There is something missing in my knowledge.

We don't have context (you may indicate from where that statement is), so this is hard to understand. It is also not clear what "it" refers to in the second line. This looks badly written to be honest. It reads a bit like claiming that a significant interaction implies homogeneity across all levels, but that seems nonsensical. If anything it should be the opposite. (You may actually be right not understanding this.)
